# @Query, @Modifying vs Native update query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I would like to know which one of the above two methods have better performance when it comes to updating a lot of records in one go. I did browse the  web but I couldn't find anything as to how the @Query works when we have to bulk update records.

Answer (score 0):

As hibernate supports bulk operations(example via `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`), there is no one better than the other performance-wise.

The only thing you have is the overhead of translation of `JPQL` queries to `SQL/native` ones.